# Using a Short URL to redirect a User in Wordpress without changing the URL in browser

Tags: wordpress, redirect

So I have a Wordpress environment with a custom URL structure.

mydomain.com/artist/theartistname

This all works nicely.

However, I'd like to use my short URL for my PRO users so they can share their shortened URL to their artist page like this:

mini.me/theartistname

I wasn't sure of the best approach here, because Wordpress isn't going to know what to do with those requests without some adjustments. For clarity mini.me/artist/theartistname works fine, I just need to lose the /artist/ part of the URL.

1. I DO NOT want it to redirect in the browser to mini.me/artist/theartistname, it needs to retain the shortened URL if possible.
2. All other traffic served to mini.me that isn't an artist page will just get redirected to the mydomain.com instead.

Any ideas on where I'd even start on this one, or is it even possible?

Comment: You should be able to use [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/204210) with some extra conditions specific to “pro” members